# Is there an easy one-shot solution to the preprocessor namespace pollution introduced by the WIN32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

As we all know, including `<windows.h>` pollutes **all** namespaces in C++ by having one preprocessor #define per Win32 API function that can either take multibyte or UTF-16 input. An example is:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFont CreateFontW
#else
#define CreateFont CreateFontA
#endif
```

I've used the native Win32 API for quite a few years now, but I'm just about giving up! In any non-trivial project there are enough name collisions to make your face turn blue.
**Please, oh please can someone come up with a solution which doesn't require me to #undef such define macros on a case by case basis after the fact?** I want to take affirmative action before this causes any bugs.

And I always use Unicode / UTF-16, so in the case of CreateFont, I would call CreateFontW directly in my code; I would not use the macro define. Is there someone who has a solution to this, like a complete header with #undef's to wrap together with windows.h includes?

An example error that creeps up everywhere, is the fact that a generic name like "GetMessage()" is taken up.

```
font.cpp(78) : error C2039: 'GetMessageW' : is not a member of 'FontManager'
```

When all you want is your class to have a member function called void GetMessage().So frustrating.

Comment: This is one of the costs of backwards source compatibility.

Comment: Sure, just don't use Microsoft method naming, and stick to lowercase Java-style, or underscore C-style method names ;)

Comment: theatrus: I asked for a solution, not for a workaround (-:

Comment: Please vote this up: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6656174-have-a-version-of-windows-h-that-doesn-t-define-ma

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cleanest solution is not to call the Windows API functions directly in your program and instead to write an abstraction layer that can call the functions you need.  This way, you only need to include the Windows API headers in a handful of source files and the macros are much more manageable.

This also has the added benefit of improving the portability of your code since only a small part of it will rely on the Windows API itself and all the rest of it will call your abstraction layer.

Even if you don't care about portability, an abstraction layer still has a lot of benefits:  your code will be easier to read and more maintainable because the complexity of making the API calls will be encapsulated in the abstraction layer (some of the Windows API functions have a lot of functions that you don't usually care about).

Since you are using C++, an abstraction layer can also allow you to translate Windows API error codes into exceptions, if you prefer to use exceptions.

An abstraction layer also helps to make your code more easily testable (it's a lot easier to mock your abstraction layer than it is to mock parts of or all of the Windows API).

Comment: This is actually a good answer, or at least as good as I can hope to get. I should definitely at least try to contain the "damage", as you suggest. Alas, I was actually naive enough to hope that someone had a header with proper #undefs floating around. I'll give you the accepted answer if no one else comes up with something better in the next hour.

Comment: @Mads:  The problem is that usually you need some of those macros (most or all of the functions are declared using macros), and everyone needs a different set of macros.  You couldn't have a standard set of `#undef` directives.

Comment: @James McNellis: That is not the case for the trivial unicode macros, which represents 90% of the problem. I call the W versions directly anyway.

Comment: @Mads:  Oh, I see.  Well, usually you `#define UNICODE` (VCBuild/MSBuild will do this for you if you set the project properties to Unicode) and call the non-suffixed form.  Most projects don't call the suffixed forms directly.

Comment: @Mads:  In that case, you could probably write a script pretty quick that searches for lines of the form `#define Name NameW` and generate `#undef` directives for each `Name`.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to accept this answer. I haven't been on the site since Friday (:

Comment: @Mads:  No problem at all.  I envy your ability to stay away from this place for so long.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is very good, and the one I recommend whenever possible.  Unfortunately, such an abstraction layer is tedious to implement and it doesn't solve the whole problem.

- You have to use the [pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) religiously to keep any and all WinAPI types out of the abstraction layer's header files.  The Windows headers should be included *only* in implementation (`.cpp`) files and never in headers.
- In practice, you end up having to make a lot of your own classes that capture essentially the same information as an underlying WinAPI type (e.g., a LOGFONT) because the client of the abstraction interface needs to pass and receive it.  You end up needing a lot of boilerplate code to translate between your abstraction layer types and the WinAPI types.
- The big refactoring necessary to introduce the abstraction layer can be a lot of work in a legacy codebase, especially if that code is shared among many projects.

The implementation of the abstraction layer requires including windows headers.  Suppose one of the platform-independent types you introduced to enable an abstraction layer has a method called `GetFont`.  The platform-independent code that relies on it will see `GetFont` because there will be no mention of `<windows.h>` in that translation unit.  But the implementation file (the `.cpp` file) that implements the abstraction layer on Windows will have a conflict with the `GetFont` preprocessor macro because it must include `<windows.h>`.  So using pimpl limits the scope of the problem, but it does not solve it completely.

What I've started doing, both in newer code which uses good abstraction layers as well as older code that wasn't good about preventing platform-specific leaks into the namespace, is to create wrappers for the WinAPI headers.  I replace all the `#include <windows.h>` lines in the code I control with `#include "apiwrappers/windows.h"`, which is a reference to a file that looks roughly like this:

```
// Prevents Windows headers from defining macros called min and max, which
// conflict with identifiers in the C++ standard library.
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#endif

// Distinguishes between different types of handles so that we get better
// error checking at compile time.
#ifndef STRICT
#define STRICT
#endif

#include <windows.h>  // the "real" <windows.h>

// Lowercase far and near are perfectly reasonable names for local variables
// and parameters, so we don't want redefinitions of them.
#undef far
#undef near

// But lots of other Win32 headers use FAR and NEAR, which are typically
// defined to far and near.  We need them to be empty.
#ifdef FAR
#undef FAR
#define FAR
#endif
#ifdef NEAR
#undef NEAR
#define NEAR
#endif

// Windows defines macros to select between the "ANSI" and "wide" versions
// of many API functions (e.g., GetMessage macro expands to GetMessageA or
// GetMessageW).  We undefine many of these here to avoid naming collisions.
// Call the specific -W functions explicitly instead of relying on these
// macros.
#undef GetFont
#undef GetMessage
// ...
```

I'm growing the list of `#undef`s as I resolve collisions.  I don't have a comprehensive one to offer.

For other WinAPI headers, I do something similar, but the rest of them are much simpler.

Comment: it's not for everyone for many reasons, but a library like Qt where the abstraction and translation is done for you is another option IF it works in your use case.

Comment: @Conrad Jones:  I haven't worked with Qt in a long time, but my recollection is that the Qt headers included windows.h and thus spread the namespace pollution throughout the project.  In fact, it was Qt application where I learned about the details of windows redefining `near` and `far`.

Comment: No they don't they use the pimpl idiom, so the windows headers get included in the Qt source files not yours.