# How do I resolve naming conflicts with headers that use the preprocessor to redefine common function names?

Tags: c++, windows

EDIT: I found a similar question, and the answers are basically that windows.h is bad and you must either rename your functions or #undef the macros:  [Other's library #define naming conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080635/others-library-define-naming-conflict)

However, I believe mine is still different due to the conflicting behavior of LoadLibrary under debug and release builds.

---

I am programming on Windows using Visual Studio and I ran into a few peculiar issues with preprocessor directives used by windows.h and the headers it includes.

Our project had a function in its own namespace, `MyProject::FileManager::CreateFile()`. After including windows.h our code failed to compile due to a linker error stating that it could not resolve MyProject::FileManager::CreateFileW (note the W at the end of the function name). This was not a static function, it was a member function of a `FileManager` object that was being called with `file_manager.CreateFile(...)`.

When highlighting the function in Visual Studio a tooltip displayed the following:

```
#define CreateFile CreateFileW
```

We were puzzled but just renamed the function as a workaround. However later we ran into a similar issue with the `LoadLibrary` function we were trying to use from the Windows API. Compiling in Debug mode, `LoadLibrary` was defined as `LoadLibraryW()` which took an LPCWSTR (wide string) as a parameter. When I tried building in Release mode this function was now defined as `LoadLibraryA()` which takes a normal LPCSTR. This broke our build because the code was written under the assumption that `LoadLibrary` took an LPCWSTR.

So, my question is, how should a programmer deal with this? Should I just wrap my calls to LoadLibrary with #ifdef's checking for Debug or Release mode? Or is there a more simple solution?

Also, I found an interesting header file on github which appears to have been created for the sole purpose of #undef'ing all these function names:

https://github.com/waTeim/poco/blob/master/include/Poco/UnWindows.h

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/LearnWin32/working-with-strings

Comment: Such are the hazards of macros, you can't really escape these when you #include windows.h.  It tends to come to a good end anyway when the client code #includes it as well.  But that's hardly a guarantee.  Pick another name or use #undef.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111899/is-there-an-easy-one-shot-solution-to-the-preprocessor-namespace-pollution-intro

Comment: If you're getting `LoadLibraryA`, make sure `UNICODE` is defined (see first link) or just use `LoadLibraryW` directly.

Comment: is it an option to wrap your internal libs in a namespace?   That is why namespace was added to the language.

Comment: @EvilTeach -- a namespace wouldn't help; these are macros that are defined in windows.h, and they infect everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things I generally do to cope with this:

- Isolate all Windows system calls in a Windows-specific layer.  For example, if I'm working with the file system API, I'll typically have `win/filesystem.h` and `win/filesystem.cpp` to wrap all the calls.  (This is also a good place to convert Win32 errors into `std::system_error` exceptions, remove unneeded/obsolete/reserved parameters, and generally make the Windows API more C++ friendly.)
- Avoid using Windows-specific types.  Allowing definitions like `DWORD`, `LPTSTR` and `BOOL` to infiltrate all levels of your code makes dealing with `Windows.h` that much more difficult.  (And porting too.)  The only files that should `#include <Windows.h>` should be your wrapper C++ files.
- Avoid using the Windows redirection macros yourself.  For example, your wrapper layer should call `CreateFileW` or `CreateFileA` directly instead of relying on the macro.  That way, you don't need to depend on the Unicode/Multi-byte project setting.

**Example**

`win/filsystem.h` might contain definitions like this:

```
namespace win32
{
  class FileHandle
  {
    void* raw_handle_;
  public:
    // The usual set of constructors, destructors, and accessors (usually move-only)
  };

  FileHandle CreateNewFile(std::wstring const& file_name);
  FileHandle OpenExistingFile(std::wstring const& file_name);
  // and so on...
}
```

Any part of your code can include this file to access the file system API.  Since `win/filesystem.h` does not itself include `<Windows.h>`, the client code will be uncontaminated by the various Win32 macros.

Comment: Could you please expand on how you'd isolate windows API calls? I am not sure how that solves the problem. Wouldn't the preprocessor still propagate those macros? Also, I didn't consider your third point, which seems like a god solution (just avoid the macro).

Comment: It solves the problem by including `Windows.h` only where it's needed.  So, `win/filesystem.cpp` sees the `CreateFile` macro, for example, but no one else does.  If you have a `CreateFile` method elsewhere in your program, it's unaffected.  Also, to be clear, the wrapper layer _only_ adapts the Win32 API.  It doesn't contain any business logic or references to business objects.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that windows.h tries to support two different string models: strings consisting of single-byte characters and strings encoded in unicode (defined by microsoft as two-byte characters). Almost all of the Windows API functions have two different versions, one that takes single-byte character strings and one that takes two-byte character strings. You're supposed to write your code with the generic names (such as `CreateFile`, `LoadLibrary`, etc.) and let windows.h take care of mapping those names to the actual API functions. For single-byte characters those two are `CreateFileA` and `LoadLibraryA`; for two-byte characters they are `CreateFileW` and `LoadLibraryW`. And there are a bajillion more, of course. You choose the model at compile time by defining the macro `UNICODE` in every compilation unit.

Incidentally, the `'A'` suffix stands for "ANSI", and the `'W'` suffix stands for "wide character".

This is particularly insidious when you write code that tries to isolate the Windows dependencies into a handful of source files. If you write a class that has a member function named `CreateFile`, it will be seen in source files that don't use windows.h as `CreateFile`, and in source files that do use windows.h as `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`. Result: linker errors.

There are a several ways around this problem:

1. always `#include <windows.h>` in every header file; that's a compiler performance killer, but it will work. (windows.h was a major motivator for precompiled headers in early C++ compilers targeting windows)
2. always use the doctored name, either `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`; that will work, but at the cost of losing the flexibility of being able to change the underlying string model when you're making API calls; whether that matters is up to you.
3. don't use any of the Windows API names; potentially painful if you use the same naming convention as Windows; not at all painful if you use snake case, i.e., all lower-case with underbars to separate words. For example, `create_file`. Alternatively, use a local prefix or suffix: `MyCreateFile` or `CreateFileMine`.